# How to delete few top rows and last row from a CSV file using python

Tags: python, excel, csv, pandas, numpy

I have CSV files those I can't edit using Excel. I want to make a dynamic code to delete top few rows (before header row) and last row without inputting row numbers. Code I am using right now is:

```
FIRST_ROW_NUM = 1  
ROWS_TO_DELETE = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 
18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 5421344}
with open('filename', 'r') as infile,open('filename', 'w') as outfile:
     outfile.writelines(row for row_num, row in enumerate(infile, FIRST_ROW_NUM)
                    if row_num not in ROWS_TO_DELETE)
```

The problem with this code is I have to manually input rows number to delete them.

Another issue I have is the number of rows to delete is not constant and changes from file to file.

The sample CSV is attached [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0N-G5EzKChlcDR6UDQxVzMxTVE)

I want a code that can somehow delete those rows without any input from my side.

Note: There is no info about the last row in the CSV but it is something like this:

```
Grand Total: - -  - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -  - - - -  - -  - - -
```

Comment: Does "until header row" mean that you want to delete the header row also, or only rows before the header row?  What pattern is characteristic of the header row, or the prior or succeeding row, that can be used to distinguish them from any other row in the file?

Comment: Sorry, that was a mistake, I have edited the question @rd_nielsen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be done using Python's [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#module-csv) library to aid with parsing the file, and the use of itertools [`dropwhile`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html?highlight=dropwhile#itertools.dropwhile) and [`takewhile`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html?highlight=dropwhile#itertools.takewhile) functions to pick out the rows you want:

```
import itertools    
import csv

with open('Test.csv', newline='') as f_input, open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_output:
    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input)
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)

    # Skip over initial lines until the header row
    next(itertools.dropwhile(lambda x: x[0] != "Report Fields", csv_input))

    # Write rows until the total row is found
    csv_output.writerows(itertools.takewhile(lambda x: "Grand Total" not in x[0], csv_input))
```

This reads each row of the CSV file until it finds a row with the first column containing `Report Fields`. It then skips this row. Now it writes all the remaining rows to an output CSV file until the first column entry contains the words `Grand Total` and then stops.

Comment: it gave me **Error: iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the file in text mode?)** error to solve this I replace rb and wb with rt and wt respectively and it ran but the out file has nothing except headers. @MartinEvans

Comment: I have updated the script, it was designed for Python 2.x. The error message implies you are using Python 3.x

Comment: Do I have to create a new file every time as it is not creating the file?. Also, now it is giving **UnsupportedOperation: not writable** error, which I think is because the file might be opened in the read-only state. Bear with me as I am a pretty newbie and forcing my way through all this. @MartinEvans

Comment: It reads one file, and creates another. Make sure you don't have `output.csv` open in another application when running the script. It will not work if you try and make both files have the same name.

Comment: It ran but is returning an empty file with header row only @MartinEvans

Comment: It would help if your sample file had some actual rows in it. The one you gave only had a header row. There were no data rows and no total row to test with.

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('file_name.csv', skiprows=27)
df.drop(df.index[5421327]) #5421327 = 5421344-27
```

You can use pandas and read_csv module to do it. 
Skiprows define line numbers to skip (0-indexed) or number of lines to skip (int) at the start of the file.
And at the end drop col with 5421344 index.

It's for static values. 
For dynamic if rows before rows or NaN you can use this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = read_csv('file_name', skiprows=1)
df.dropna(axis=0, inplace=True)
df.drop(df.iloc[-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Open your input and output files, and then:

```
for line in infile:
    if <line matches header row>:
        break
outfile.write(line)
for line in infile:
    if <line matches grand total line>:
        break
    outfile.write(line)
```

Comment: I want to create a new file as outfile. Also, when you are saying **<line matches header row>** do I have to save header row as a list?

Comment: How you handle that line depends on how you need to check it to determine whether it is the header row.  I think it's most likely that you could use a substring search or a regex to match some known value(s) in the column header.

Answer (score 0):

I'd first read in the entire file as a string and split it on what seems to be the indicator for the dataframe you are trying to read `'Report Fields'`.  Then you can eliminate the last row by splitting on newlines and indexing the list to include all but the last with `[:-1]`

```
with open('infile.csv', 'r') as infile, open('outfile.csv', 'w') as outfile:
    txt = infile.read().split('Report Fields')[1]
    outfile.write('\n'.join(txt.split('\n')[1:-1]))
```

Comment: I'm getting the error **TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not _io.TextIOWrapper** @piRSquared

Comment: Where is the error.  What I've written works for me.

Comment: it is running now, but it is deleting everything when used with other files @piRSquared